Quarkus JWT EllipticCurve Signing and encrypting SRJWT05028: Signing key can not be created from the loaded content
I am trying to implement JWT authentication using innerSign and encrypt in quarkus framework.
application.properties with keys configuration:
smallrye.jwt.verify.algorithm=ES256
smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=/security/jwt/ec/privateKeypkcs8.pem
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.algorithm=ES256
smallrye.jwt.encrypt.key.location=/security/jwt/ec/publicKey.pem
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=/security/jwt/ec/publicKey.pem
mp.jwt.decrypt.key.location=/security/jwt/ec/privateKeypkcs8.pem
smallrye.jwt.decrypt.algorithm=ECDH_ES
smallrye.jwt.decrypt.key.location=/security/jwt/ec/privateKeypkcs8.pem
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=true

privateKeypkcs8.pem:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgW6VBGNFX5tSq6Ayi
A8dGk9CMI+nrZEbuVHqa5tvz+I6hRANCAARhfohbEbZYj81uSz+yBw4Bj5VDdWEX
cJ+E6FO8G5tXsPFYyHVlwHRfQcAcoEtCwmH2wrqyomf/FlTNpWKJCxFs
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

privateKey.pem contents:
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIFulQRjRV+bUqugMogPHRpPQjCPp62RG7lR6mubb8/iOoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEYX6IWxG2WI/Nbks/sgcOAY+VQ3VhF3CfhOhTvBubV7DxWMh1ZcB0
X0HAHKBLQsJh9sK6sqJn/xZUzaViiQsRbA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----


publicKey.pem contents:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEYX6IWxG2WI/Nbks/sgcOAY+VQ3Vh
F3CfhOhTvBubV7DxWMh1ZcB0X0HAHKBLQsJh9sK6sqJn/xZUzaViiQsRbA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

privateKey.pem generate with command:
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out /security/jwt/ec/privateKey.pem

publicKey.pem generate with command:
openssl ec -in /security/jwt/ec/privateKey.pem -pubout -out /security/jwt/ec/publicKey.pem

privateKeypkcs8.pem generate with command:
openssl pkey -in /security/jwt/ec/privateKey.pem -out /security/jwt/ec/privateKeypkcs8.pem

JWT generate code:
Jwt.claims(claims.claimsMap).jws().innerSign().encrypt()

This error occurs:
io.smallrye.jwt.build.JwtSignatureException: SRJWT05009: 
    at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.sign(JwtSignatureImpl.java:109)
    at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.innerSign(JwtSignatureImpl.java:153)
    at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtClaimsBuilderImpl.innerSign(JwtClaimsBuilderImpl.java:296)
    at io.backend.util.JwtTokenUtils$EC.generateTokenString(JwtTokenUtils.kt:69)
    at io.backend.util.JwtTokenUtils$EC.generateTokenString(JwtTokenUtils.kt:45)
    at io.backend.JwtTokenService.generate(JwtTokenService.kt:44)
    at io.backend.http.RestController$login$2.invokeSuspend(RestController.kt:104)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:111)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPerTaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPerTaskExecutor.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SRJWT05028: Signing key can not be created from the loaded content
    at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.sign(JwtSignatureImpl.java:102)

It does not matter which file is used (privateKey / privateKeypkcs8) - always the same exception occurs.
Please help me with this. Where is my mistake ? how to fix this ???????
The same setup but with RSA configuration works but I dont want RSA!
